# Linq to SQL ignoring first database record

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've got a really odd problem whilst trying to query a table I've just dropped into our database for use as a custom role provider for a MVC 4 application.

I have three table, User, Role and UserRoles.  At the moment for testing purposes I just have a single role in the database, with ID = 1.

In the UserRoles table I have two records,

1. userRoleID 1, userID = 1,  roleID = 1.
2. userRoleID 2, userID = 14, roleID = 1.

Now when trying to run the following linq (hardcoded for testing and example purposes) it will never return the first record in the database (userRoleID = 1)

```
   var userRoles = from ur in _db.UserRoles
                   join r in _db.Roles on ur.roleID equals r.roleID into rj
                          from subR in rj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   join u in _db.Users on ur.userID equals u.userID into uj
                          from subU in uj.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   where ur.userID == 1
                   select ur;
```

So in this example the code returns null. If I change the where clause to say where ur.userID = 14 then it will return the second record as expected.

If I then switch the database records around so that they become

1. userRoleID 1, userID = 14, roleID = 1.
2. userRoleID 2, userID = 1,  roleID = 1.

It will now only return the record where userID 1. Has anyone come across this as I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: if you omit the joins and just execute `from ur in _db.UserRoles where ur.userID == 1 select ur;` does it work this way? If you execute the query with the joins, but without the `where` clause, do all results come back?

Comment: This is where it gets a bit more bizarre. Removing the joins and the where clause returns both records as expected. However for the record with userID = 1 I get both the expanded Role and User tables included, which is ultimately what I want. but for userID = 14 I only get the expanded User table despite that user having the same role value as the first user.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain to me what the first record is and how you "switch them around" if a table and a query result, per definition in the SQL standard, HAS NO ORDER?

If you want an order, put in an order by. Otherwise SQL Server will return the results in whatever order it likes. This is fundamental - SQL is set based, SETS have no intrinsic order.

Comment: I can tell the first record by going to the database and manually switching the data over in the userID field of the table. record 1 being the first one entered into the database.

Comment: No, you can not. YOu can tell the first record that was returned then, but that is not a "first record by definition". You basically say "I roll a die and demand that the first number comes all the time". If you want a defined order, put it into your sql statement. That is beginner knowledge - first page, first book. SQL has no order unless you impose one.